# Drinfeld upper half plane admissible open

Tags: algebraic-geometry, grothendieck-topologies, rigid-analytic-spaces

I have a possibly silly question about the Drinfeld upper half plane. It is "well-know" that if $K$ is a complete local field then $\Omega_K = \mathbb{P}^1(\mathbb{C}_k) \backslash \mathbb{P}^1(K)$ has the structure of a rigid analytic space. A proof of this is given in proposition 6.1 of Drinfeld's paper "Elliptic Modules I" (1974). From what I can understand it goes as follows.

We know $\mathbb{P}^1_K$ has the structure of a rigid analytic space. First we define an increasing chain of admissible open affinoids $U_1 \subset U_2 \subset \cdots$ in $\mathbb{P}^1_K$ whose union is $\Omega$. Drinfeld then states that to show $\Omega$ is an admissible open subset it suffices that:

> For any morphism from an affinoid space $f: \mathrm{Sp}(A) \to \mathbb{P}^1_K$ factoring through $\Omega$, $f$ in fact factors through some $U_i$.

This seems like a natural enough claim. In fact, it's not too hard to show that for a general rigid analytic space $X$, if $\{ U_i \}$ is a set-theoretic covering by admissible (not necessarily affinoid) opens, then this covering is admissible if and only if for all morphisms $g : \mathrm{Sp}(A) \to X$, the cover $\mathrm{Sp}(A) = \cup_i g^{-1}(U_i)$ has a finite affinoid refinement.

In particular, if we knew $\Omega$ was an admissible open, the condition in the box above would imply that $\{ U_i \}$ is an admissible cover of $\Omega$.

My question is: what am I missing? How do we know that $\Omega$ is an admissible open?

I know that we can pick some admissible covering of $\mathbb{P}^1_K$ by affinoid analytic spaces, say $\mathbb{P}^1_K = \cup_j V_j$ with $V_j \cong \mathrm{Sp}(A_j)$. Then $\Omega$ is an admissible open $\iff \Omega \cap V_j$ is admissible for all $j$. I feel like this should help.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but I don't really see the problem. Being admissible open means that there is a cover by rational subdomains such that the image of any map $Sp(A)\to \Omega$ can be covered by a finite subcover. Since any $U_{i}$ admits such a cover, the statement in the box implies that also $\Omega$ admits such a cover (namely the union of the covers for all the $U_{i}$'s).

Comment: In everything I say you should of course intersect with your given affinoid cover $V_{j}$ of $\mathbb{P}^{1}$, and then use the statement you mention at the end.

Comment: No you are correct. There's no problem. I realize now I was just confused about the relationship of admissibility in the affinoid $V_j$ and admissibility in the whole space. This can be easily explained by viewing $V_j$ as a rigid space with it's natural structure, which is to say the admissible subsets of $V_j$ are precisely the admissible subsets of $\mathbb{P}^1$ that are contained in $V_j$! If you want to write your comment as an answer I'd be happy to accept it. I will also write down the details soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the question, it's enough to show $\Omega \cap V_j$ is admissible open in $\mathbb{P}^1$ for all $j$. Clearly $\Omega \cap V_j = \cup_{i} \left( U_i \cap V_j \right)$ is a union of admissible opens (in $V_j$). Let $W_{ij} = U_i \cap V_j$. Each $W_{ij}$ is admissible in both $V_j$ (when considered as a rigid space) and $\mathbb{P}^1$. Furthermore, by definition, if we know $\cup_i W_{ij}$ is admissible in $V_j$ then it's also admissible in $\mathbb{P}^1$.

Suppose we have a morphism $f : \mathrm{Sp}(B) \to V_j$ with image contained in $\Omega \cap V_j$. Composing with the natural embedding $g_j : V_j \to \mathbb{P}^1$, we get a morphism as in the box in the question. Applying the claim in the box, we see that it factors through some $U_{i_0}$, which implies $f$ factors through $W_{i_0 j}$, so $\{ f^{-1}(W_{i_0 j}) \}$ is a (single-element) finite cover of $\mathrm{Sp}(B)$. This is exactly what we needed to show $\cup_i W_{ij}$ is admissible open in $V_j$ so we're done.